# Installing matplotlib via pip on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to use matplotlib on Ubuntu 12.04. So I built a wheel with pip:

**python .local/bin/pip wheel --wheel-dir=wheel/ --build=build/ matplotlib**

Then successfully installed it:

**python .local/bin/pip install --user --no-index --find-links=wheel/ --build=build/ matplotlib**

But when I'm trying to import it in ipython ImportError occures:

> In [1]: import matplotlib
>
> In [2]: matplotlib.get_backend()
>   Out[2]: u'agg'
>
> In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot
>
> ImportError
>   Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /place/home/yefremat/ in
>   ()
>   ----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot
>
> /home/yefremat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py
>   in ()
>        32 from matplotlib import docstring
>        33 from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
>   ---> 34 from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
>        35 from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
>        36 from matplotlib.image import imread as _imread
>
> /home/yefremat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py
>   in ()
>        38 import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar
>        39 
>   ---> 40 from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
>        41 from matplotlib.blocking_input import BlockingMouseInput, BlockingKeyMouseInput
>        42 from matplotlib.legend import Legend
>
> /home/yefremat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/**init**.py
>   in ()
>         2                         unicode_literals)
>         3 
>   ----> 4 from ._subplots import *
>         5 from ._axes import *
>
> /home/yefremat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py
>   in ()
>         8 from matplotlib import docstring
>         9 import matplotlib.artist as martist
>   ---> 10 from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
>        11 
>        12 import warnings
>
> /home/yefremat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py
>   in ()
>        36 import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
>        37 import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
>   ---> 38 import matplotlib.tri as mtri
>        39 import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
>        40 from matplotlib.container import BarContainer, ErrorbarContainer, StemContainer
>
> /home/yefremat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tri/**init**.py
>   in ()
>         7 import six
>         8 
>   ----> 9 from .triangulation import *
>        10 from .tricontour import *
>        11 from .tritools import *
>
> /home/yefremat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tri/triangulation.py
>   in ()
>         4 import six
>         5 
>   ----> 6 import matplotlib._tri as _tri
>         7 import matplotlib._qhull as _qhull
>         8 import numpy as np
>
> ImportError:
>   /home/yefremat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_tri.so:
>   undefined symbol: _ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base9_M_unhookEv

May be I'm doing somethig wrong? Or may be there is a way to turn off gui support of matplotlib?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't installing with the package manager `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`?

Comment: Thank you for attention, but yes. I'm using this package on random machine and clearing up all environment after that. So, I need to install this package all over again. That's why I decided to use python wheel to speed up this process. @rhodysurf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was in gcc version. During building and creating wheel of package pip uses system gcc (which version is 4.7.2). I'm using python from virtualenv, which was built with gcc 4.4.3. So version of libstdc++ library is different in IPython and one that pip used.

As always there are two solutions (or even more): pass LD_PRELOAD environment variable with correct libstdc++ before entering IPython or to use same version of gcc during creating wheel and building virtualenv. I prefred the last one.

Thank you all.